# how do i set up a HTTP test for a Route53 -> EC2 -> API endpoint reverse proxy pathway

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, http, aws-lambda

I have built an EC2 reverse proxy (Nginx) that communicates with an external API endpoint over the internet. I have a Route53 DNS with an A record linking to my EC2. There are a few endpoints (Nginx locations) and depending on which url you hit, you are redirected to a specific proxy location, and forwarded to the right endpoint on the external API. It all works great.

Now i want to create some type of job that will test this process periodically to ensure that it's running and notify me if it's not. AWS has so many tools and i think i need to use Lambda and API Gateway.

I'd like to hit my url(Route53 DNS) go thru the EC2 and receive a response from the endpoint server. My site does this, postman can, but i can't figure out how to accomplish this in an automated way and alert me based on the response values.

how can i test my full pathway (www.example.com/option -> nginxEC2 path('/option') -> www.endpoint.com/option) and be notified based on the results.

EDIT: i need to be able to send a body with this. if i send it without body the server returns 404, if i can send with a body/payload, i'll get a response.

EDIT: basically looking for a way to hit my DNS, which thru A record, routes to my reverse proxy, to an endpoint. i just need to do an HTTP request to the Domain, and get and answer back and know the status code.

Mark B's solution is the closest as the free site he sent me has an option to pay for this service. gonna leave it open a few more days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely don't need API Gateway for this. That wouldn't help you test this at all. API Gateway would just give you an entirely new API that you would need to test.

You could use Lambda for this as you mentioned. You would write a Lambda function that hits the URLs you want to test, checks the results, and sends you a message over SES or SNS or some other means when it fails. The Lambda function could be configured to automatically run on a schedule.

However, AWS already has a service that does exactly what you are looking for: [Route53 Health Checks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/health-checks-types.html).

What you are describing is called an HTTP health check or HTTP uptime monitor. There are tons of services that provide this feature, [some of them free](https://uptimerobot.com/).

Comment: Thanks MarkB, looking into it. will give you credit for the answer once built. much appreciated Sir.

Comment: @sao updated my answer with an entirely free option.

Comment: MarkB: i have a health check running now. its coming back as "UNHEALTHY" but i think it's working. in the Health Checkers tab, i see "Failure: 404: Resolved IP:" + my EC2 IP. so its hitting the EC2 and reading the IP. the external API endpoint requires auth, and if sent without in Postman, i get the same 404. I think healthcheck is reporting that 404 as a non connection, whereas if i could send my auth, I'd get a good response (200, or i'd even take a 300 error, just to know the thing is talking) is there a way to send a body with healthchecks, as the endpoint server will give 404 without auth

Comment: same scenario with uptime robot. hmmm.. does anyone know if i can send a body with these? that'll get me the info i need.

Comment: @sao I think uptime robot has the ability to set headers on the request. But I think that's a paid feature. You might have to evaluate some paid services, or go back to developing it yourself with Lambda.

Comment: yeah, it sounds like we're getting into that paid services territory, i have gone back to  Lambda

Comment: @sao, one thing I thought of with Lambda, you could have it post a 1 for OK, and a 0 for failure or something like that to a custom CloudWatch metric. Then you would have a chart in CloudWatch of exactly when your service was up/down. You could also have CloudWatch send an alert if needed, although that alert isn't as customizable as just sending an email straight from Lambda would be.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the word that you're looking for is **trace** -- you want to trace requests along your application. AWS offer for that is X-Ray. As you see in their [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-usage.html), you need to use their SDK to instrument your application, which talks to a deamon in your EC2 instance. You can then integrate with CloudWatch and SNS to be notified upon errors (e.g. 4xx codes): https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/using-amazon-cloudwatch-and-amazon-sns-to-notify-when-aws-x-ray-detects-elevated-levels-of-latency-errors-and-faults-in-your-application/
Hope it helps!

Comment: Fabio, can i hit my DNS with this as well? There are many services that allow this to happen easily, the domain will follow thru the EC2 and the endpoint as I have a reverse proxy on Nginx running. But i want to hit the front most entry point, instead of the EC@, i want to hit my domain www.example.com

Comment: I'd contact AWS support for sure, but I don't think it makes sense to have this type of logic (add header trace) during DNS resolution. Can you share more details of the use-case? For X-Ray, I found this page with services that can be integrated with it: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-services.html

Comment: looking into the suggestion. The use case is that I want to test my DNS, EC2 and endpoint all at once. If any one of those goes down i have an issue. Granted the DNS is probably super safe on AWS Route 53, but I still want to test it.

Comment: Route53 provides a checking tool in which you can simulate requests. You may set up some automation around it: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-test.html